# Android Studio 4.0 file > New > Activity OR Fragment not working

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, build-tools, android-studio-4.0

I have android studio 4.0 installed & I am unable to create new activity OR fragment from File > New menu.

All that happens is just a gradle build & files don't show up after I click the `Finish` button.

Following is the system environment.

```
Studio Version: 4.0
SDK build tool: 30
Gradle wrapper: 6.1.1
OS: macOS Catalina (10.15.2)
Machine: MacBook Air (2017
```

I am using an android navigation UI version: `2.2.2` and also tried to create new activity/fragment from navigation file using `New Destination` still no result.

Let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please open your app build.gradle file and delete debug config from signingConfigs and try again:

```
 signingConfigs {
   // delete this entire debug block 
   debug {
        storeFile file('file path')
        storePassword 'password'
        keyPassword 'password'
        keyAlias = 'password'
    }
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly that did work, I don't understand what's the relation & what could be the alternative for signing config.

Comment: This worked, but why ? how ? 
How can these two things possibly be linked ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution and I think it might also comes rescue you.You have to update the minSdk version to the required version. You probably the min version required while trying to create the activity.
Follow the step below:
step-1:File--->Project structure
[File--->Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUb2f.png)

step-2: Modules--->Default config
[Modules--->Default config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmhi5.png)

Now set your minSdk to the required value and hit the apply followed by ok.
Hopefully you will get the activity windows now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for version 4.1.2:

on the top menu of android studio click on Build --> Clean Project, after that Build --> Rebuild.

It will tell you the error causing trouble, for me it was that android studio did not properly close the manifest tag in the manifest file. Once I closed the tag and rebuilt the project again, everything worked fine.