# Android Studio problem-cannot adds a new activity or fragment in a project file

Tags: android, android-studio

When I upgrade Android Studio to 4.0.1, it was fine. However, when I was working on a project, I wanted to create a new fragment which was when the problem occurred.

After pressing finish, Android Studio loads but can't create a new fragment or any activity:

[image: Screenshot of New Android Activity Wizard in Android Studio]

First I think it happens only for this project.
But then I see I can't create any activity or fragment in any project.

My Android Studio version is 4.0.1.

Comment: Didn't even know it can be created like this:) Try File -> Invalidate cache / restart or add any information about error.

Comment: I don't have any error, just can't create any activity or fragment.   'Invalidate cache / restart'- I try it but it cant work.

Comment: It hard to find out what the problem without any errors;) Anyway you can create activity like everybody do. Just create new class and extend it from activity:) Or if you really need this useless feature just reinstall the Android Studio. Might be it's some bug...

Comment: yes. After finding nothing, I reset my Android Studio. Then It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not giving any errors, then probably your activity is made but is not showing in the android studio. You should go to the project directory and check if the files are added or not.

To go to the file directory of the project you can right click on any activity(click on main activity as you have that by default) and go the show in windows explorer and check if the fragment or activity is created or not.

Or you can navigate through the documents.

Comment: I checked the project directory but I fount there nothing.

Comment: Then you must revert the upgrades

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing debug config from signingConfigs inside app/build.gradle file.

Did work for me as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485683/4445159).

```
signingConfigs {
// delete this entire debug block 
   debug {
         storeFile file('file path')
         storePassword 'password'
         keyPassword 'password'
         keyAlias = 'password'
     }
 }
```